# Confusion over NancyFx MediaRange

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

I'm trying to create a WebAPI with Nancy that only responds to certain accept header types. What I want is to reply on a custom accept type, application/json, or if the client has added */* as an accept header, in which case I'll return JSON here too.

I thought doing the following would solve my problem (I've omitted some code for brevity / confidentiality):

```
return this.Negotiate
            .WithMediaRangeResponse(new MediaRange("MyCustomType"), () => return new Response() {....})
            .WithMediaRangeResponse(new MediaRange("application/json"), () => return new Response() {....})
            .WithMediaRangeResponse(new MediaRange("*/*"), () => return new Response() {....})
```

I anticipated that given this code, if the accept header contains MyCustomType then the first expression would be executed, alternatively, if the accept header contains either application/json or */* then their respective expressions would be executed. If a request came in without any of those three values then another action will occur (haven't figured out how to default to a BAD REQUEST yet).

However, what seems to be happening is that the */* MediaRange expression seems to be called for any accept headers that are not MyCustomType or application/json. So if I pass "text/html" it's getting a valid response which isn't what I want. I want the */* to only match if the client has passed */* in the accept header and not be a catch-all for any other accept header types.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you will need to add a BeforeHook to inspect the Headers and decide if you will allow it to pass through or not.Something like this
`pipelines.BeforeRequest += (ctx) => {
    return <null or a Response object>;
};`
where `null` will let request through and `Response` will be `BAD REQUEST`

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try